# Countifs, where a criteria can match multiple text options

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets in Google Sheets:

- **All contacts w. week/month/year**, where we pull all of our deals for the year
- **Weekly Marketing analytics**, where we match up all of this information on a weekly basis

In the **Weekly Marketing analytics**, every column from B2 to BB2 is a week number (1-53), and A1 is the current year (2021 with this sheet).

I am currently trying to count, every deal that matches specific values in our **All contacts w. week/month/year** documents, so that I only see marketing sourced deals:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIFS('All contacts w. week/month/year'!$S:$S;C$2;'All contacts w. week/month/year'!$V:$V;$A$1;'All contacts w. week/month/year'!$E:$E;{"PAID*";"ORGANIC_SEARCH";"SOCIAL_MEDIA"})))
```

- *'All contacts w. week/month/year'!$S:$S;C$2* - Matching current week of the main sheet.
- *'All contacts w. week/month/year'!$V:$V;$A$1* - Matching the current year (2021).
- *'All contacts w. week/month/year'!$E:$E;{"PAID*";"ORGANIC_SEARCH";"SOCIAL_MEDIA"})* - This is the column I am having trouble with. This is the column with the deal source information, and since I'm only interested in deals from marketing, I have tried to narrow it down to our marketing channels.

Currently this formula still returns deals that have been sources OFFLINE or REFERRED, and I cant work out why? What am I missing here or is there any other way to solve this?

Also thanks in advance for any help and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
'All contacts w. week/month/year'!$S:$S=C$2;
'All contacts w. week/month/year'!$V:$V=$A$1; 
 REGEXMATCH('All contacts w. week/month/year'!$E:$E; 
"PAID|ORGANIC_SEARCH|SOCIAL_MEDIA")
 )
```